# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` Error - Already exists in AndroidManifest

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I've searched SO all day and I'm still not able to find a solution to this problem, so hoping someone here can help.

React Native - 0.67.4

**Error**

[image]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="N/A">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The thing that has me going in circles is that almost every answer on SO refers to adding             `android:exported="true"` the `<activity />` tag, but I already have.

[image]
Here's my `build.gradle`

[image]

I've looked at the Merge Manifest in Android Studio and looked at all of the resources files and I see `android:exported="true"` in all of them.

If anyone could please help point in another direction, I would really appreciate it. I know there are ton of related posts on SO, and I almost always use them. But for this one, I just can't a fix. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the code for Merged Manifest.

Comment: @user18309290 It's the 2nd screenshot in the post